# Is it possible to render two headers on one screen using React Navigation?

Tags: react-native, header, react-navigation

I'm writing an iPad / Android Tablet app with React Native and I'm using React Navigation for the navigation.

The mock up I received has a screen which is split in half (in landscape mode) with two different headers. Is is possible to achieve this with react navigation?

What I've tried is setting `header: null` in the navigation options for the screen, and then rendering two components on that split screen, each of the components has React Navigation's `Header` component as the first child. This somehow does not work (the header does not get rendered).

Comment: You should share what you tried so far, your code. You can also share the mockup in order to have a precise response.

Comment: Hi J. Hesters. How did you get on with the answer below?

Answer (score 0):

Like you can see in the [source of `Header`](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation-stack/blob/6a76bf6703726e6aceb5db8fc8ccba2f4e66f326/src/views/Header/Header.js#L462) it does not render if the header option is null:

```
_renderHeader(props) {
  const { options } = props.scene.descriptor;
    if (options.header === null) {
      return null;
    }
    ...
}
```

So using the `Header` component manually will not work.

You could just create your own Header components with a title and a "back" touchable. If a designer gave you a mock up I assume the Header must be styled very differently from original Header component anyway :)

Your component could look like this:

```
export default class MyCustomHeader extends Component {
  handlePress = () => {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    navigation.goBack(); // or .navigate() to whatever you want
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.handlePress}>
          <some-icon>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        <Text>My title</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

With proper styling of course :)